# How to grab 2 columns of data from a Mysql database and convert it to a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

Ok, So I am trying to create an e-mail newsletter sign-up for my site, and the file I created to fetch the 2 columns called `Name` and `Email` from my database, doesn't just save those 2 columns to a csv like I want it to. Instead it saves the whole table. I am confused as to what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated here is the code.

```
<?php

function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'export.csv')
{
    $csv_terminated = "\n";
    $csv_separator = ",";
    $csv_enclosed = '"';
    $csv_escaped = "\\";
    $sql_query = "select `Name`, `Email` from $table";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);


    $schema_insert = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
    {
        $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
            stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
        $schema_insert .= $l;
        $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
    } // end for

    $out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
    $out .= $csv_terminated;

    // Format the data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
        {
            if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
            {

                if ($csv_enclosed == '')
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                } else
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed . 
                    str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $schema_insert .= '';
            }

            if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
            }
        } // end for

        $out .= $schema_insert;
        $out .= $csv_terminated;
    } // end while

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
    // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    //header("Content-type: text/csv");
    //header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    echo $out;
    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: this code saves all name/e-mails from table to csv, what is your question?

Comment: i couldn't get you, how many fields(columns) you ahev in your database table?

Comment: there is 4 total and only need 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function and pass it fields as an array:

```
 function arrayToCsv( array &$fields, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $encloseAll =    false, $nullToMysqlNull = false ) {
   $delimiter_esc = preg_quote($delimiter, '/');
   $enclosure_esc = preg_quote($enclosure, '/');

   $output = array();
   foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
      if ($field === null && $nullToMysqlNull) {
        $output[] = 'NULL';
        continue;
    }

    // Enclose fields containing $delimiter, $enclosure or whitespace
    if ( $encloseAll || preg_match( "/(?:${delimiter_esc}|${enclosure_esc}|\s)/", $field ) ) {
        $output[] = $enclosure . str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure . $enclosure, $field) . $enclosure;
    }
    else {
        $output[] = $field;
    }
}

return implode( $delimiter, $output );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by pass it fields as an array?

Comment: Also the code alone doesnt run get the unexpected $end error